# Help me improve my PCB design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, pcb-antenna

I have made this PCB design with the help of a reference circuit to run an e-paper display with an nRF52810.

I have doubts about the followings:

1. Do signal track lengths or widths need to change?
2. Is there a track path that I am supposed to avoid?
3. Do I have to reposition any of the components, such as the capacitor?
4. Is the antenna position good for 2.45 GHz?
5. Anything else that I can do to make the design better?

PCB images:

[image]

Note: The reason I added 0 Ω resistors to the DIN, SCK, CS, DC, RST, and BUSY signal lines is to get a point to check the signal on these lines; similar reason for RX & TX line 0 Ω resitors.

[image]

[image]

With copper pour:
[image]

[image]

PCB: Board/schematic Eagle file and schematic PDF files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V15FcPwsA7bqJr51HuZX33l3oaKnhMBV?usp=sharing)

Below some circuit references:

1. nRF52810 Minimal Circuit (Reference [here](https://github.com/NordicPlayground/nrf5-eagle-reference-design)).
2. EPD driver circuit reference is [here](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/8/87/E-Paper-Driver-HAT-Schematic.pdf)

Please ignore the via under the 24-pin FPC connector on the left side which has a trace to the VCC pin. I don't know why it was showing in the first place, but I corrected it now with its connection to GND.

Reference nRF52810 QFAA DCDC, [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16p64CxcVitq7MId-mccNHJuEABGQQTLS?usp=sharing)

Comment: ah okay, so improve?

Comment: Design review questions are very open-ended and don't necessarily have one right answer or there can be different opinion based answers. How do you decide which answer is most correct in such case? Your question does have multiple specific points which you want answered, but some of them are unrelated to each other.

Comment: Instead of adding 0 ohm resistors (each with 2 pads and a component placement) to create a test point why not just add a small SMD SIP header along the group of traces? You wouldn't need to install the header component and you would have a single open pad for a test point. (There may actually be single pin test point components in your available component library.)

Comment: It might be helpful to slide the X5 and X6 connections further away from the antenna traces,  The chip mfg might have recommended clearances for placing other components near the antenna traces. As for the antenna itself, be sure to follow the mfgr's details for shape, layering, and size as accurately as possible.

Comment: @Justme i understand your point but as beginner even after reading some points regarding PCB design, I want some expert general opinions on PCB design, which I'll implement from next time onwards. Point like GND via, Close position of Decoupled capacitor, no ground copper Pour other side of antenna I found while last time showing my PCB design to an expert. So I want similar of those advice with respect to actual example.

Comment: @JustdoinGodswork Do you want only PCB design advice? Or also schematic design advice? Or circuit design advice? Because not all things  are only about designing the PCB.

Comment: Widen the clearance space between the traces and vias of DIN and SCK signals (to the right of the resistor positions) to prevent creating the isolated island that then needs another via.

Comment: You are breaking up your bottom ground pour with long traces, effectively weaken it a lot. If your switch/strobe/clock frequency is low enough and everything have strong local decoupling, you can probably get away with it. If not, try to avoid long traces on that layer by routing most of it on top layer and only use short tracks on bottom when you need to cross something on top layer. “Stitching” the track via top and bottom, while avoiding bottom. Even better, try to do floorplanning of parts, where and on which sides to avoid long tracks all together. How does your decoupling situation look?

Comment: Less than ideal trace connections to L4, R1, C15, C19.  Swap positions of D2 & D3 plus rotate both 180. Route TX trace to front of X6 instead of under 0 ohm resistor (if used). Be sure to run a design check, at least one unrouted connection visible.   [That's all for now]

Comment: @Justme Circuit design for now I follow the references and try to understand the reason for it. For Schematic design as in the representation of circuit if you meant, for these projects the schematic won't affect the functioning I guess but if you see anything wrong in the above schematic, please tell me I'll appreciate it. But mainly I'm only looking for PCB design that will affect the functioning of the circuit and will require PCB manufacturing again and again. I can't afford that.

Comment: @Nedd 1. I used resitor in EPD lines because I also want the EPD to seperate from the rest of the circuit, so i'll be able to directly run EPD through another ecternal driver circuit just in case.     

2. The antenna clearance deatils willbe mentiaoned in nRF52810 datasheet?     
3. I'll increase the clearance of via of DIn and SCK. By this I understood is there should be GND copper pour around those vias.     

4. Swapping D3 and D4 was so obvious after you mentioned, so I think I need to observe more about the component placements.   
Thanks a lot, I got some direction to look at now.

Comment: How wide are your traces?

Comment: @winny Ground plane is breaking bottom layer because of long track: So I can shorten the track as bottom to cross over the anything on top layer and use rest of the track on the top layer only. I'll spend more time for better component placement. I only followed decoupling capacitors positions as per refrence only, so I think its the best

Comment: Please post schematic if you can. ICs often come with decoupling guidelines but many sub circuits you design still comes with decoupling requirements. Is your top plane pour Vcc? Also, why so wide PCB? You have quite some space in the middle.

Comment: @Tyler I used 0.254 mm, for each track I have designed. The one used for nRF52810 chip is 0.2 which used in the reference circuit. Also those pins are pretty close can't go higher than that.

Comment: @winny Added Schematic files links of nRF52810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't made too many changes already here is another group of improvements to consider.

**Improve the long trace coming from X4 p23:**
Move C22 up slightly, catch the X4 P23 connection at the left pad of C21 then route to the right and down, cross the horizontal group of traces at a minimum length location.  Continue routing to D3 but now go above D1. Rearrange again after other changes.

**Tighten up traces at the center of the board and minimize vertical bottom trace lengths:**
The 0 ohm resistors can be staggered horizontally then their traces brought closer together.
Move DIN resistor left about 1/2 the length of the resistor.
Move SCK resistor right just beyond the edge of the DIN resistor, then move resistor up tight against DIN trace.
Move CS resistor left beyond SCK resistor, then move up tight against SCK trace.
Repeat with DC, RST, and BUSY resistors.
The extra space below the resistors should now allow more space to route D1, D2, D3 traces.
The reduced width of all these traces will now minimize the trace length needed to cross the board.
Reroute D1 long diagonal trace (on top side first), then continue under the BUSY resistor then left, place via to jump over the minimum length point of the horizontal trace group, add another via and route to C19.

**Reduce the center vertical trace lengths on bottom side:**
Slide the RST long diagonal trace right, then slide DC long diagonal trace (and via) right, then slide the BUSY long diagonal trace left (with an extra angle segment), reroute long X3 trace (on top side first) down to the DC trace then place a via, cross DC, DST and BUSY, place via, route to X5.

**To clean up the lower left of the board:**
Rotate C14 ccw, move upward.
Rotate C13 ccw, move upward close to C14.
Move R2 under C13, connect directly to X4 p2.
Move T1 right.
Rotate R1 180 deg, move to left side of T1.
Move R1 and T1 further away from mounting hole.
Move L4 to left of T1 and above R1, connect to T1 under body.
Move C24 down in line with D2.
Move C23 to left of T1.
Slide D1, D2, and D3 left to minimize trace lengths.

**Improve X6 area:**
Move TX resistor to left of RX resistor, route TX trace to bottom of X6 p1 pad.
Move both RX and TX resistors upward so that they are clear of the corner of X6.

**Improve gnd connections at top left:**
Give C19 its own gnd via to right of pad.
Give C16 its own gnd via to right of pad (move other trace if needed).
Give C21 its own gnd via to right of pad.
Move C15 gnd via closer to C15 pad.
Reroute long trace from C19 (on top side first) to minimize required bottom trace length.

**Improve X4 pin to pin connection (if this is not an error):**
Remove the tiny existing trace within the tight finger area.
Slide C15 slightly to the right.
Move the via on X4 p17 to the right.
Make the X4 p16-15 connection outside the finger area.

**Extra via under X4:**
If this extra via was previously connected to a pin it may still have the net name associated with it. As long as the original net is now fully routed just delete the via.

Answer (score 3):

Just some observations:

If EMC is a concern, I would strongly recommend using four layers with at least one solid reference plane (recessed under the antenna). Or, if you want/need to stick to two layers, at least keep signal lengths on the bottom layer to an absolute minimum to have a as solid as feasible reference plane.

The board isn't 100% routed. The line under the big connector on the left appears to be an air wire.

The thermal vias under the chip on the right will suck away solder. However, that might not be much of a problem for a hand-soldered prototype.

If neighboring pins of chips or connectors are on the same net, I would avoid connecting them with an as short as possible track as that might end up looking like an unintentional short after soldering. It might be okay with the chip on the bottom right as there should be enough solder mask between the pins. The connector on the left appears to be a finer pitch, so here I would consider avoiding a direct connection. That depends on the solder mask capabilities of your PCB fab, of course.

Comment: as winny mentioned also, i'll definetly going to improve the bottom layer to minimal signal tracks. Left unrouted tacks I mentioned in the edited, idk why it cam but I fixed it to ground now. What can I do else for left connector (24 pin FPC connector), shall I use via with those pns? if avoiding direct connection?

Comment: @JustdoinGodswork In this case it should be possible to add a track to the left of the lower pad and connect it with the trace that is leaving the upper pad. Just avoid copper between the pads. It might be totally fine the way it is, depending on the circumstances (PCB fab capabilities, soldering technique, ...). But it's a good idea to avoid those direct connections when practicable.

Comment: Re air wires: "You may know those two nodes are on the same net, and I may know they're on the same net, but are the electrons going to know that?"